# Node.js parsing JSON from iOS URLSession body

Tags: ios, json, node.js, swift

Sending a JSON from an iOS device using `URLSession`. I'm sending:

```
let body = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: order.toJSON())
// { "customer": 123 }
request.httpBody = body
request.httpMethod = "POST"
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    ...
}.resume()
```

If I print the body just after that, I do get a valid JSON:

```
print(String(data: request.httpBody!, encoding: .utf8)!)
// {"customer":123}
```

Then, in the server side `nodejs` I have the following code (node or javascript are not my main domain):

```
module.exports = function (ctx, req, res) {
    console.log(ctx.body)
    // { '{"customer": 123}': '' }
    ...
```

My question is, why is it adding the original JSON to a JSON `key` and how can avoid it?

Using `JSON.parse` doesn't work as it gets the hole JSON is a key of an empty value (as the example).

Answer (score 0):

What is the `toJSON()` method you're using there? it looks to me like you're stringifying it twice, and for some reason, that method is wrapping it in a dictionary.

Here is a complete, working Playground snippet:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let url = URL(string: "http://requestb.in/<<your-requestbin-key>>")
var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
let order = ["customer": 123]
let body = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: order)

request.httpBody = body
request.httpMethod = "POST"
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    print(response!)
}.resume()
```

Notice that there's no need to call `toJSON()` anywhere (nor is that a built-in Swift method).

Requestb.in's response:

[image]

Comment: Sorry not to be clear. `toJSON()` is a custom method, returns a `[String: Any]` dictionary. I'll take a look on your snippet and try to reproduce hardcoding the dict directly, thanks

Comment: Well, looks like that's the problem right there. You're already stringifying the request body via `JSONSerialization.data()`. No need to do it twice.